# req.body returns undefined while using body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to build an API that receives a POST req to create a user but I am getting undefined errors for all of my `req.body` requests. My app is set up like this (simplified for brevity):

**User controller that gets called by Express Router in my user routes file**

/controllers/user.js

```
userController.addUser = function(req, res) {
  let user = new User();

  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.first_name = req.body.first_name;
  user.last_name = req.body.last_name;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.type = req.body.user_type

  // This returns undefined as does all other req.body keys
  console.log("REQ.BODY.EMAIL IS: " + req.body.email);
}
```

**User Route File:**

/routes/user.js  - requires user controller above

```
router.post('/user/create', userController.addUser);
```

**Main App:**
all routes and controllers work per my tests except where req.body.* is used

index.js - main app file

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', routes);
```

I have looked through the Express documentation and through countless StackOverflow posts with no luck. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Can we see your post request please?

Comment: Try `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: @sLaks I did that and that's how I found out it's undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure if two parsers work in parallel

Comment: @crescentfresh Please also post your client code which actually does the posting to your web server.  It's possible you're just not setting anything on the request there.

Comment: @dvsoukup my issue was sending the data via postman using form-data instead of x-www-form-urlencoded :-/

Answer (score -1):

My issue was how I was sending the body to the API endpoint. I was using form-data instead of x-www-form-urlencoded with Postman. User error

Answer (score -1):

Sometime with change in version `body-parser` seems to not work, in that case just use following, this will remove dependency from `body-parser`:

```
router.post('/user/create', (req, res, next) => {

    let body = [];

    req.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    }).on('data', (chunk) => {
      // Data is present in chunks without body-parser
      body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
      // Finally concat complete body and will get your input
      body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
      console.log(body);

      // Set body in req so next function can use
      // body-parser is also doing something similar 
      req.body = body;

      next();
    });

}, userController.addUser);
```